# Todo list for Android that has the repeat option of first Friday of the month, etc

Tags: android, project-management

Is there a todo list application that has a repeat option to repeat on xth day of the month?

I know most have like repeat once a month, or every x weeks, but I cannot seem to find anything that has "repeat every 1st Tuesday of the month".

Answer (score 2):

[Todoist](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.todoist) does it. Just type "every 1st Tuesday" in the due date of your task and it should work.